# Domain Locking – Multiple Domains

Tags: actionscript-3

Noob needed some help here.

I am trying to use this code code snippets to lock a swf to couples of domain names.

```
var allowedDomains:String = "ghostwire.com|somewhere.net|elsewhere.org";

var allowedPattern:String = "^http(|s)://("+allowedDomains+")/";
var domainCheck:RegExp = new RegExp(allowedPattern,"i");
if (!domainCheck.test(url))
{
    // domain check failed, abort application
    stop();
    // abort();
}
else
{
    // domain okay, proceed
}
```

problem is even when I add my sites like:

var allowedDomains:String = "mysite.nl|mysite.de|mysite.co.uk";

The swf use the abort() function.

This one works grab the domain URL alright. But There isn't a way to add Multiple Domains

```
var url:String = stage.loaderInfo.url;
            var goodPattern:RegExp = /^(http:\/\/)(www\.)?mysite\.nl/;
            if (goodPattern.test(url) == true)
            {
                trace("This flash is hosted on mysite");
            }
            else
            {
                trace("This flash is not hosted on mysite");
                this.alpha = 0;
            };
```

The above snippets works.
But then given me two other issues.
1: I cant add more then one domain name.
2: after code obfuscated, the stage get nulled, soo when try to play the swf i get a debugger error.

TypeError: Error #1009: null object

can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong here!!!

original link here:

PS: I am a newbie, and not banned from here.
I just couldn't find my older details, and when trying to get the script to sent me a new details via e-mail, I got a message that used email which was good, wasn't into this database.

soo I a message was promp to use my google account which I did, sorry If this was wrong.

Hope to get some help consern my thread.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your second code, to check the domain you use slightly different regex, which looks for 'www', maybe try this:

```
var allowedDomains:String = "mysite\\.nl|mysite\\.de|mysite\\.co\\.uk";
var allowedPattern:String = "^http(|s)://(www\\.)?("+allowedDomains+")/";
```